# Mysql query, select from a determined point on

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

i have a table with player rankings and i want to tell a player who are the 5 players above him. How would i make such a query?

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ladder_rankings` (
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ladder_points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `player_id` (`player_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ladder_rankings
WHERE ladder_points >10
ORDER BY ladder_points DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The problem is that will show the top players and not the ones above me directly. Imagining i have 10 points. So if i am in position 230 i want the guys on 225, 226, 227, 228 and 229.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joan,
You could do a query like:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT *
          FROM ladder_rankings
          WHERE ladder_points > (SELECT ladder_points 
                            FROM ladder_rankings 
                            WHERE player_id = %current_player%)
          ORDER BY ladder_points ASC
          LIMIT 5) as NEXT_5
 ORDER BY ladder_points DESC
```

Comment: ORDER BY ladder_points DESC will still only show me the top 5 overall, ASC works but the row order is upside down.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `DESC` from your query and you'll get them

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *
FROM ladder_rankings
WHERE ladder_points >10
ORDER BY ladder_points 
LIMIT 5) ORDER BY ladder_points DESC
```

Wrap that in another `SELECT` to get the results in the desired order

Answer (score 1):

I think just change DESC to ASC

Comment: You could store the values in an array first, then output to the rows in reverse order (regarding your comment about the wrong order)